# flutter - code highhlight and format in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web, syntax-highlighting

I am working on a project where I have to show code on the flutter web. I have found a package [package link is here](https://pub.dev/packages/any_syntax_highlighter)

but the problem with this package is I am not able to format the code.

How can I do this or format the code ?

code looks like this...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this package,

It has higher ratings, is more updated  and supports formatting.

```
https://pub.dev/packages/widget_with_codeview
```

https://pub.dev/packages/widget_with_codeview

Comment: But sir I just want to provide the code to the user. I want him to copy and paste.

Comment: Can you remove the " " in your code around "axios.post..." and try? Currently it is a string due to the " ".

Comment: Same response sir. I asked my friend he told me add \n in code while uploading and while displaying replace \n with LineBreak() but the linebreak function is not working n nobody knows it.